# Как получить доступ к элементу li с атрибутом?

Tags: jquery

Как получить доступ к элементу li с атрибутом `type="2"`?

```
<div>
<ul><li type="2"></li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('li[type="2"]');`